# code anaylsis node missing from Visual studio 2008

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, code-analysis

I want to have a look at the VS code analysis tools. [This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173498.aspx) msdn page suggests:

Expand the Configuration Properties node.

Expand the Code Analysis node.

Unfortnately when I expand the configuration properties node I only have the options:
General,
Debugging,
c/C++,
Linker,
Manifest tool,
XML Document Generator,
Browse Information,
Build Events and
Customer Build step.

This is in a win32 console application in Visual Studio Professional Edition v 9.0.21022.8 RTM with .net framework 3.5 SP1. Any one know what I'm missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Code analysis is not part of the professional version, but only in the more expensive Team System edition. You can however use [FXCop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb429476(VS.80).aspx) instead.

Comment: I thought FxCop was a c#/ clr tool?

Answer (score 1):

Try [StyleCop](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/sourceanalysis) and/or [FXCop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb429476(VS.80).aspx) depending on what you want to analyse